# Not able to check connection from a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment that has a `recycler view` with swipe to refresh.  On refresh, I reach out to a server and pull list from a db that updates the `recycler view`.  All of that works fine.  My issue is this, I have a method that checks if I have internet in my activity:

```
public boolean isConnected(){
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)
            getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

This works great from my activity, but when I try to call it within the fragment the `"getSystemService"` creates an error.  I've tried using listeners from the fragment to the activity or just placing this method within the fragment and it doesn't work. Is it possible to check the internet status within a fragment, or is that something that can only be done w/n an activity?

Comment: logcat? code of how are you calling the method? It's possible to check wherever you have a context.

Comment: Error stack trace please?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check connectivity from a fragment, you should get context, in your case the activity :

```
public boolean isConnected(){
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)
            getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

Or with a static method

```
public class Utils{
    public static boolean isConnected(Context context){
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected();
    }
}
```

And call it from fragment with

```
Utils.isConnected(getActivity());
```

Comment: or he can make a method static and add it to some Util class